# Using callbacks on trait objects

Tags: rust

I’m trying to use a callback function on a trait object. I reduced my problem to the following code ([playpen](http://is.gd/qJGub6)):

```
trait Caller {
    fn call(&self, call: fn(&Caller)) where Self: Sized {
        call(self)
    }
}

struct Type;
impl Caller for Type {}

fn callme(_: &Caller) {}

fn main() {
    let caller: Box<Caller> = Box::new(Type);
    caller.call(callme); // does not work
    //callme(&*caller);  // works
}
```

which results in

```
<anon>:14:12: 14:24 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Caller` [E0277]
<anon>:14     caller.call(callme); // does not work
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Adding a `Sized` bound to `Caller` results in:

```
<anon>:3:14: 3:18 error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `Caller` is not object-safe [E0038]
```

I really don’t understand why I need the `Sized` bound on the trait. Funnily it works if I use the callback directly. How do I get this to work?

Edit: Thanks to the answer I now came up with a nice solution

```
trait Caller {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Caller;
    fn call(&self, call: fn(&Caller)) {
        call(self.borrow())
    }
}

struct Type;
impl Caller for Type {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Caller { self }
}

fn callme(_: &Caller) {}

fn main() {
    let caller: Box<Caller> = Box::new(Type);
    caller.call(callme);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument `call` in `fn call` takes a trait object `&Caller`, so calling it requires coercing the `self` reference (of type `&Self`) to a `&Caller` trait object. The coercion is only possible when `&Self` is a thin pointer rather than a fat pointer like a trait object or a `&[T]` slice. `&Self` is a thin pointer exactly when `Self: Sized`. The compiler defaults to `Self` in traits not being `Sized`, and so the extra restriction is required. The [`Sized` trait](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/the-sized-trait/) represents that the type has a size that is known at compile time, there is no need to store extra info (next to the pointer, making it "fat") to compute it at runtime.

Unfortunately, this leaves a hole: AFAIK, it's actually not possible to have such a method be a default method and still be able to call it on trait objects, since a trait object `&Caller` has `Self = Caller` which isn't `Sized`. However, it should work if the method is implemented manually for each type:

```
trait Caller {
    fn call(&self, call: fn(&Caller));
}

struct Type;
impl Caller for Type {
    fn call(&self, call: fn(&Caller)) {
        call(self)
    }
}

fn callme(_: &Caller) {}

fn main() {
    let caller: Box<Caller> = Box::new(Type);
    caller.call(callme);
}
```

The `call` method declaration in the trait no longer needs the `where Self: Sized` since it isn't trying to do the trait object coercion itself, and the concrete implementations have much more control over how the `&Caller` trait object is obtained. For `Sized` types, it works directly, like the original `where Self: Sized` code.

Comment: One thing I'm still unclear on after reading this - is there a way to make the OP's code work?

Comment: Err, yeah, forgot to actually answer the question. :)

Comment: Thank you, but what I don’t understand is why it is not possible to transform &Self to &Caller. Shouldn’t that be just an identity transform as &Self is already a &Caller? Edit: The answer is probably that &Self is not &Caller but might be something else but sounds like it should be fixable in rustc.

Comment: If `Self` isn't `Sized`, it could be `SomeOtherTrait`, or `[SomeType]`, i.e. `&Self` is some "random" fat pointer that isn't `&Caller`. We would need a bound like `Self: SizedOrCaller` to ensure that either `&Self` is a thin pointer or `&Self` is `&Caller`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found a nicer solution of my problem. I now require the implementation of `borrow_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Caller`. Unfortunately it is not possible to require `BorrowMut<Caller>` as a trait bound on `Caller` since that creates some cycle.